# Pandas - After Successfully Writing to a New Workbook, Excel Gives Invalid File Error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

When running my code with a macro workbook, I get the following error: "Excel cannot be open the file 'filename.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid," but when I run my code on an xlsx file, I do not get this error and the new workbook loads up fine.

I am using Pandas to read the file with the openpyxl engine. I've tried solutions with the XlsxWriter, and that hasn't helped.

Appreciate any suggestions

This is how I write to a new workbook:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path2, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists = 'replace') #Append data to exisiting sheet
dataClean.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data Input', header = False, index = False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but recently I have ran into the same issue and this was the only post I've found about it.

`writer.close()` already saves the file according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html). There is no need to call `writer.save()` manually.

You could also use a `with statement`:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path2, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a', if_sheet_exists = 'replace') as writer: # Append data to exisiting sheet
    dataClean.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data Input', header = False, index = False)
```

Comment: Appreciate it - actually ended up doing the same